# JS: date to number conversion through +

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

Today I had read a Google Analytics code snippet which is inserted on the site and stumbled upon a piece of

```
i[r].l=1*new Date();
```

I thought that this snippet is optimized for maximum
I was wondering why they converted date to number through "1*new Date()", but not "**+** new Date()"?
That would be shorter.
Is there something strange about + what I should know?

Comment: May be it's a less magic? I really didn't see any difference.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, both will work in all browsers as far as I know. Personally I would use a few bytes more and do `(new Date()).getTime()` so I'm using built in methods, and not relying on "typecasting" a date object.

Comment: So if there are no difference, why they don't use shorter one?